# Mulți threaded task xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I work in xamarin for a week now but I notice that working on a single cpu thread is boring and slow. How can I make a multithreaded app, like on cpu 0 to run an infinite loop that search for something in every second on cpu 1 to run the actual code(when a button is pressed, a task is done by the cpu) and soo on.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/using-threads-and-threading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    //your background task here
});
```

This will perform your task on a background thread. Note that any UI changes must be done on the main thread.

Edit: also, in your case you probably don't want to await the Task.Run call so code continues to execute without waiting for the Task to return;